# Binary Search Tree is Balanced Javascript

Tags: javascript, binary-search-tree

I want to add a method that says that if the binary search tree is balanced, I thought I would use a method that gives me the maximum and minimum value of both sides and then see if the difference is 0 but I can't get the values from the branches.
If anyone knows what I could do or some more efficient method to see if the BST is balanced.

```js
function BinarySearchTree(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
  }
  
  BinarySearchTree.prototype.insert = function(value) {
    var nuevo = new BinarySearchTree(value); 
    if(value > this.value) {
      if(!this.right) {
        this.right = nuevo;
      } else {
        this.right.insert(value);
      }
    } else {
      if(!this.left) {
        this.left = nuevo;
      } else {
        this.left.insert(value);
      }
    }
  } 

  BinarySearchTree.prototype.contains = function(value) {
    if(value === this.value) return true;
    if(value > this.value) {
      return !!this.right && this.right.contains(value);
    }
    if(value < this.value) {
      return !!this.left && this.left.contains(value);
    }
  }

  BinarySearchTree.prototype.breadthFirstForEach = function(fn, array) {
    if(!array) {
      var array = [];
    }
    !!this.left && array.push(this.left);
    !!this.right && array.push(this.right);
    fn(this.value);
    !!array.length && array.shift().breadthFirstForEach(fn, array);
  }
  
  BinarySearchTree.prototype.size = function() {
    if(!this.left && !this.right) return 1;
    if(!this.left && this.right) return 1 + this.right.size();
    if(this.left && !this.right) return 1 + this.left.size();
    return 1 + this.left.size() + this.right.size();
  }
  
  BinarySearchTree.prototype.print = function() {
    
  }

BinarySearchTree.prototype.remove = function (value) {
  if (value < this.value) {
    this.left = this.left && this.left.remove(value);
  } else if (value > this.value) {
    this.right = this.right && this.right.remove(value);
  } else if (this.left && this.right) {
    this.value = this.right.findMinValue();
    this.right = this.right.remove(this.value);
  } else {
    return this.left || this.right;
  }
  return this
}

BinarySearchTree.prototype.findMinValue = function () {
  return this.left ? this.left.findMinValue() : this.value;
}

BinarySearchTree.prototype.minDepth = function () {
 return this.left && this.right ? this.size + Math.min(this.left.minDepth()) + Math.min(this.right.minDepth()) : null 
}
```

Comment: you will create a new tree everytime you create a new node

Comment: @EugenSunic No, the BinarySearchTree class just represents a node in the tree. Each insert only creates a new node and appends it to the tree in the correct place.

Comment: "*I can't get the values from the branches*" - it seems you know well what to do already. So just go ahead now and add a new method that returns the values you need (e.g. an object with `min` and `max`)!